# How to return a string in a Django DRF response without AttributeError?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

this snippet is not working how I want:

```
return Response({"Error": "build {} does not exist"}.format(build_name), status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)
```

error:

```
AttributeError:
'dict' object has no attribute 'format'
```

What am I doing wrong?  I'm using Python 3 btw.

Comment: Yes, it won't work. Observe carefully what you are trying to do 
```return Response({"Error": "build {} does not exist"}.format(build_name), status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)```


it should be : ```return Response({"Error": "build {} does not exist".format(build_name)}, status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are applying `.format` to `dict` instead of `string`.
Try:

```
return Response({"Error": "build {} does not exist".format(build_name)}, status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)
```